# MIPS Summation of a number of series with offset

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

So I'm trying to write a MIPS program to calculate the summation of a series of numbers. I need to take 3 parameters: first integer in series, number of integers in series and offset.

What I tried so far is writing a while loop that looks like the following:

$t0 -> first integer number input

$t1 -> number of integers in the series input

$t2 -> offset

[image: while loop]

---

It somewhat works but what I'm having troubling with is storing the previous integer correctly as in:

Initial number = 3

Number Of integers in series = 3

Offset = 2

3+0 = 3

3+2 = 5

5+2 = 7

and then do the sum of 3 + 5 + 7

Any help is appreciated...

[image: Example Output]

Comment: Code should be added as text, not in the form of images.

Comment: You seem to be over-complicating things. Just print `$t0`, add `$t0` to some available register where you keep the series sum (e.g. `$t3`), add `$t2` to `$t0`, and repeat.

Comment: I have a bad tendency of over complicating my thoughts, thanks for the help. And will keep in mind the code as text for the near future.